# "iPhone cannot be activated"

Tags: iphone, itunes

I was searching through the Lost And Found in my local school and found an unclaimed iPhone. I tried to turn it on but i got this message saying that it cannot be activated when I tried to connect to my local network. I already tried to restore and trying to update the device but I got this error message[image].These solutions all came up inconclusive. I'd highly appreciate a solution.

Cheers!

P.S. I assume that the device is not bound to a Canadian carrier. The device also did not have a sim card present in the device.

Comment: This might be a stolen phone. The best action you can take is drop it off at your local police station or constabulary and be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

Give it to the Police. iPhone  is in ‘Lost Mode”. 
Owner is searching for it.

Comment: I appreciate your response but...The problem is that the iPhone was the in Lost And Found for several months at this point. I would also assume that the student would have found out and contacted the office. Secondly, I asked the office if any student was looking for an iPhone 5s and they said no. So i assume the student gave up on it. Also when an iPhone is in 'Lost Mode' it directs you to the lock screen, in my case I can't even get past the iPhone setup screen before an error message shows up.

Comment: The only way i could see it not being able to activate the device is that if the owner contacted the carrier and disabled the device, but as I stated previously I highly doubt that it is bound to a carrier.

Comment: IMO Apple products should be faced as Rolex watches.  The owner & only him/ her should be able to have this iPhone.  So. Because this iPhone is not yours- you should not claim it. In any case just think of that. Even if ya get your hands to this device you will not n

Comment: Be able to make it work.

Comment: Alright! Thanks so much for your help! l'll drop it off at my police station asap :)

Comment: Its the best thing that you can do. Just think of that,,,,how much trouble you will get into when the owner decides to look for it.  Until now no one (for many reasons hasn’t look for this device) but think of that moment whenever it comes. ....

Comment: All the owner has to do is login to his/hers iCloud account and launch the Find my iPhone app. When this device connects to any WiFi , the owner will be able to locate it AT ONCE.